# About church inquisitor caster level 3.5E

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, cleric, prestige-class

So me and my group just finished our first dungeon, and I play a cleric. I'm now at level 4, and I just upgraded to a prestige class that I fit, Church Inquisitor, because it seemed easy to acquire which was in approval with the DM. I have the travel, Inquisition, and Sun domain. The thing I'm interested in is that apparently Church Inquisitor gives a divine caster level every level instead of every other level. I don't quite understand the whole caster level and domain spells thing, and whether or not the Church Inquisitors ability to get caster levels faster stacks with the caster level increases of cleric. Sorry if this is a noob question.

So **TL;DR:**, can someone please give me a number of spells for each level for like the first 3 levels of church inquisitor, as well as domain spells? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Church Inquisitor (Complete Divine p.26) grants a spellcasting level in one existing divine spellcasting class at every single level of Church Inquisitor.

Given that you are at Cleric 4 when you start picking up levels in the Prestige Class, this means that as you take levels in Church Inquisitor you continue to level your casting as a Cleric, with the exact same spells you have and you add the Inquisition domain to your spells you can pick as your daily domain spells, as well as gaining the domain power of the Inquisition domain (+4 to dispel checks).

I suspect that you confuse the level of the spells you get with the spellcasting level. A Cleric 4/Church Inquisitor 1 casts spells like a 5th level Cleric, which means that you have access to 3rd level spells (at 5th level Cerlic casting this means 1 regular spell + 1 domain spell). A Cleric 4/Church Inquisitor 2 would cast like a 6th gets 2+1 3rd level spells, and a Cleric 4/Church Inquisitor 3 would gain access to 4th level spells.

**So in short, picking levels of Church Inquisitor advances your spells in the exact same way as picking levels in Cleric would.**

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm a little dissapointed that Inquisitor doesn't actually increase my spell casting ability any more than cleric, but it seems slightly better and looks like it will be fun to roleplay. I thought the level increase applied to caster level, and from what you're saying it looks like I don't get the level increase from cleric when I level up the inquisitor.

Comment: Also, because I'm now a level 1 prestige class, does this mean I'd level up as if I was a level 1 base class, or would I need the same exp to get the Inquisitor to level 2 as I would to get a cleric to level 5? I heard that prestige classes took no exp penalty, but it wasn't very specific.

Comment: @SkylerGunn What do you mean it doesn't increase your spell casting ability any more? You gain a level of divine spellcasting with every level of the prestige class.

Comment: @Ruut I meant that I thought it would double the speed of how fast my caster level increased.